# A bag contains 2 red, 3 green and 5 blue balls

Tags: probability

A ball is drawn, observed and put again in the bag. Find the probability of getting all colours different.
My teacher's solution:
2/10 × 3/10 × 5/10 × 3! × 2
I don't get why that last 2 was necessary
Edit: balls are drawn 3 times

Comment: So how many times do you take a ball out from the bag (and put it back)?

Comment: I guess you draw $3$ balls after each other. Is that correct? Further (just like you) I think that multiplying by $2$ is not correct.

Comment: Yes 3 balls sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: I expect the teacher meant to write $3\times 2$ instead of $3!\times 2$.

Answer (score 2):

The last $2$ should not be there.  The first three terms give the chance of getting specifically red,green,blue.  The $3!$ is the number of orders of colors and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to delete the last 2.

Maybe the teacher wanted to just put $3 \cdot 2$ and not $3! \cdot 2$